# Change html attribute value does not have data with onclick event using react

Tags: reactjs

I have these code,

```
export default MainContent = () => {
    handleClick = (e) => {
        const attr = e.target.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    };

    return (
        <div aria-expanded='false' onClick={handleClick}>1</div>
        <div aria-expanded='false' onClick={handleClick}>2</div>
        <div aria-expanded='false' onClick={handleClick}>3</div>    
    );
}
```

What I need to do is set **aria-expanded='true'** when click. I can't make this to data-expanded. And I only need to change clicked item.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to wrap `divs`. Then set event to the `wrapper` to delegate it. Finally, have get the data from the attribute, handle it and putting back.

```js
const MainContent = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const attr = e.target.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    // Check for attributes
    if (!attr) {
      return;
    }
    // Switch status
    const changeAttr = attr === "false" ? "true" : "false";
    // Set result back
    e.target.setAttribute("aria-expanded", changeAttr);
  };

  return (
    <section className="container" onClick={handleClick}>
      <div aria-expanded="false">1</div>
      <div aria-expanded="false">2</div>
      <div aria-expanded="false">3</div>
    </section>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <MainContent />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[aria-expanded="false"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 179, 0);
}

div[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: rgb(89, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new state, which you will change with onClick function and the value of aria-expanded will be dependent on this state

```
export default MainContent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setOpen(!open);
    e.target.setAttribute("aria-expanded", open);
  };

    return (
        <div aria-expanded={expanded ? 'true' : 'false' } onClick={handleClick}>1</div>
        <div aria-expanded={expanded ? 'true' : 'false' } onClick={handleClick}>2</div>
        <div aria-expanded={expanded ? 'true' : 'false' } onClick={handleClick}>3</div>    
    );
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aria-expanded-1brv9?file=/src/App.js:52-194)

Comment: Thank but I need to set true only the clicked element attribute. So if I clicked first one other should remain false and the first one only true :)

Comment: I've just updated the answer to make it work like you described and added a demo

Answer (score 0):

I cant use this aria-expanded as react says:

```
The attribute aria-expanded is not supported by the role list.
```

how you've used aria-* attribute!!!